# Django - consecutive dumpdata calls fail, even though work correctly when run separately

Tags: python, django, backup

I've run into an issue trying to set up automatic backups on my site. The problem boils down to the following.

I open the Python shell and I call the dumpdata command twice. It **works** for the first time and it returns **empty list** the second time. After that all further dumpdata calls return empty list:

```
>>> python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.management import call_command
>>> call_command("dumpdata")
[{"pk": 1, (...) // lots of data //
>>> call_command("dumpdata")
>>> []
```

To make it work again I need to restart the python shell.

Edit: I use Django 1.4 and Python 2.6

Edit2: My current hypothesis is that the problem is related to this issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5423 - identified 5 years ago and according to Django 1.5 release notes, to-be resolved in the next release. Does anybody have an idea how to workaround this issue without altering the 1.4 framework code being run on the machine?

Edit3: However sql dump of the whole database is only 0.5 MB, which makes it rather unprobable that the serialization is running out of memory. And anyway, wouldn't I get an explicit error in such case?

Edit4: Mystery solved. As Tomasz Gandor correctly determined, the problem was that shell executes the commands in one transaction, and after one of the commands causes DBError, further DB calls are ignored, as described here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10813 . Why the DB error during the first dumpdata wasn't explicitely reported remains a mystery to me.

Comment: I've made a simple test and works fine for me. What type of database do you use? Also which Django/Python versions?

Comment: Django 1.4 and Python 2.6. I suspect the problem is data-dependent, as it does not occur on my local machine, where I have different db content (less data in general).

Comment: "I used this patch and changed model.objects.all() to model.objects.iterator() in django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py. After that I was successfully able to dump a considerably big database (1Gb SQLite file). Python process resident memory size was at about 20M all the time" (in your refered page)

Comment: @danihp - I'm aware of the patch, however I would prefer to avoid modifications of the framework code running locally to avoid maintenance overheads in the future. Do you think there is no other way to go from here?

Comment: @danihp - also, my db is really small (0.5 MB sql dump, as I've just specified in the question). Maybe my hyphotesis about https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5423 is wrong.

Comment: @PrzemysławPietrzkiewicz, is a simple change that can be performed one time only to confirm your hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that django is messing something with transactions.

I executed a simple example under the debugger:

```
# test.py
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command("dumpdata")
print "\n---"
call_command("dumpdata")
print
```

And called it like:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings python test.py > log.txt
```

My log.txt ended with "---\n[]\n"

After running it in the debugger i found, deep down in 
`django.core.management.commands.dumpdata.handle()`
that model.objects.all() keeps returning [].

I called model.objects.iterator(), and got the exception:

```
(Pdb) list(model.objects.iterator())
*** Error in argument: '(model.objects.iterator())'
(Pdb) p list(model.objects.iterator())
*** DatabaseError: DatabaseError('current transaction is aborted, commands ignored    until end of transaction block\n',)
(Pdb)
```

So, I hacked together code, which plays with the transaction itself:

```
# test.py version 2.0!

#!/usr/bin/env python
# from django.core.management import call_command
import django.core.management as mgmt
from django.db import transaction

''' 
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)
'''

@transaction.commit_manually
def main():
    # mgmt.call_command('dumpdata', use_base_manager=True)
    mgmt.call_command('dumpdata')
    transaction.rollback()
    print
    print '---'
    print
    """ 
    mgmt._commands = None
    import sys
    reload(sys.modules['django.core.management.commands.dumpdata'])
    """
    mgmt.call_command('dumpdata')
    transaction.rollback()
    print

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This spits out the whole database - every time!

Comment: You'll see traces of other attempts to circumvent it - like reloading some modules etc. It's commented out with multiline strings, so don't pay attention to it. It just didn't help.